# How to add two functions together in one??react -native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

I am trying to add these `2 Functions` in one. I am new to react-native. As in code, I tried but only the first one is working.

My question is How I can use `setSearch` and `animation` together in the `onChangetext` function?

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.searchbox}
    onChangeText={(text) => {
        setSearch(text)
        scaleValue.setValue(1)
        Animated.timing(scaleValue,{
            toValue:0.5,
            duration:100,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            useNativeDriver:true
        }).start();
     }}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that once you use setSearch(text) you're changing the state of the component and that change trigger the re-rendering of the component itself so the rest of the code doesn't run.
I've never used react native so I'm not sure 100% but if you are using a Functional component you can do something like this

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
useEffect(() => {
   scaleValue.setValue(1)
   Animated.timing(scaleValue,{
                   toValue:0.5,
                   duration:100,
                   easing: Easing.linear,
                   useNativeDriver:true
                }).start();
}, [search])


return (<TextInput
              style={styles.searchbox}
              onChangeText={(text) => setSearch(text) }/>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use an intermediate function to call them both?

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.searchbox}
    onChangeText={(text) => intermediateFunction(text)}
/>

intermediateFunction = (text) => {
    setSearch(text);
    Animated.timing(scaleValue,{
                  toValue:0.5,
                  duration:100,
                  easing: Easing.linear,
                  useNativeDriver:true
                }).start();
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're calling the intermediateFunction outside of the return body?

Comment: yes.but when I tried to run in return it gives error..

Comment: ')' expexted ahead of <safeareaview>

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the 'safeAreaView' code to check that this is working and that error isn't due to something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228269/discussion-between-richard-kemikal-general-denton-and-anonymous-mind).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new function to encapsulate the two actions you want to invoke by onChangeText.  Something along the lines of:

```
 const doSomething = (text) => {
          setSearch(text)
          scaleValue.setValue(1)
          Animated.timing(scaleValue,{
            toValue:0.5,
            duration:100,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            useNativeDriver:true
            }).start();
          }
 }

 ...

 <TextInput style={styles.searchbox}
          onChangeText={(text) => doSomething(text) />
```